# AWS S3 and Cloudfront for storage of images

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk

I'm using AWS S3 for storage my images and accessing them by Cloudfront. Here is mine access url formate. For example:

http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/qGdyRHeptWqR5sl.jpg

I want to use thumbnail for this image. Generating thumbnails at upload time is not modern approach especially when you are required a lot of different size images. It's not good in maintenance point of view. A little change in design required to regenerate all of thumbnails again.

Is there any possibility for thumbnail image to be generated on the fly by just requesting a URL something like below:

> http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/thumb/200/150/qGdyRHeptWqR5sl.jpg

OR

> http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/qGdyRHeptWqR5sl.jpg?size=200x200

OR

> http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/qGdyRHeptWqR5sl.jpg?width=200&height=200

I've tried all the above url but no success. DO i need to use some image resizing plugin to do so? Do i need to request image from cloudefront & resize it then reupload it on S3?

I'm using Java as programming language please recommend me some plugin or better approach in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions related to [ngx_http_image_filter_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) plugin for Nginx. You can install Nginx and configure it to resize images from S3 by request.

[Here](http://matthewroach.me/basic-image-resizing-with-nginx/) is article which describe how to do it.

Comment: Hi maxd, thanks for your response. I'm using tomcat server. I think this option is't suitable for apache tomcat server. Is there any other option available ?